# Getting hdmi signal of a camera to TCP/IP network and read on computer

Tags: canon, multi-camera

I would like to know if such application can be made with this type of devices and what would I require to actually read the signal on my computer?

here is a small figure I made
[image]
i plan on putting DSLRs and cine cam like this

I know that 6D MII have network capabilities but they use wireless communication which is not really stable. The 6D mII Has a mini hdmi port.

I would like to mount on network multiple cameras to make concert recording, studio session recording, game live streaming etc.

I could not find any answers on that topic since every searches return to amazon and eBay.

I'll be highly thankful for any help,

best regards;

the Link of the device I plan on using:
https://www.amazon.fr/Mirabox-Extendeur-Ethernet-Switch-extension/dp/B06WD82BPG/ref=sr_1_8?dchild=1&keywords=Adaptateur+Rj45+Hdmi&qid=1598867556&s=computers&sr=1-8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the best way to go is to use a mixer like the BlackMagic ATEM-series. I am working in a film-studio and have worked mainly with the ATEM Television Studio HD Mixer, which has all the capabilities you would want.

Mixers like these have SDI/BNC and HDMI inputs and are capable of mixing and converting each signal, using lower-thirds, live-keying (if you want to use a webcam with greenscreen) and much more. Yes, they are expensive, but if you're serious about this I would highly recommend it. You will have a better signal than through Wifi streaming or wireless transmissions...

Comment: Thanks i’ll take a look at it !

Comment: I think I'll go with the Atem mini since I only need hdmi for now, the one I'll choose will depend on its characteristics so I'll do a bit more research and if it works well with capture softwares. Thanks for your help though.

Comment: and the cdmi to ethernet will be used to extend cdmi cables so I don't have to buy 50m hdmi

Comment: That sounds like a good choice! I hope you're successful in what you're doing :)

Comment: Thanks! I hope so